# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] loading angular.js with require

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

i am not able to getting route cause of it .. as i'm just loading angular js files only

```
var commonJS = [
    'angular',
    'angular.routes',
];

requirejs.config({
    paths: {
       jquery:'libs/jquery/jquery.min',
       angular:'libs/angular/angular.min',
       "angular.routes":'libs/angular/angular-route.min'
    },
    shim:{
        "angular": {
           deps: ["jquery"]
        },
        "angular.routes": {
            deps: ["angular"]
        },
    }
});
require(['jquery'],function($){

    require(commonJS,function(){

    });
});
```

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Answer (score 0):

You probably included angular files of different version. Some of the modules are failing to load because of that.

Comment: I have checked all the files are of same version 1.2